# Imagine hotspot and selection dropdown php

Tags: php, forms, url

I have a select tag and an image with a hotspot. I would like to select a value from the dropbox and use the hotspot link as part of the selection also. Am able to get the value from the select tag but am struggling to connect the 2 values one from select tag the other from the hotspot.into the url so i can perform a GET method.

HTML

```
<form action="results.php" method="GET" name="frmres" id="frmres">
<select name="specialist_1" id="specialist_1" style="background: transparent;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:12px;border: 1px solid #ccc;scrollbar-arrow-color: #12406F;">
<option value="-1" >Select a Specialist</option>

<?php   global $database;
$database = new MySQLDatabase();
$sql="SELECT descr FROM tablenae GROUP BY descr ASC";
$result_set=$database->query($sql);
$num_rows=$database->num_rows($result_set);
if($num_rows!=0){
while($row=$database->fetch_array($result_set)){
$docSpecialist=$row['descr'];
echo '<option value='.$docSpecialist.'>'.$docSpecialist.'</option>';
}} ?>
</select>
```

IMAGE MAP HOTSPOT

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="poly" coords="414,153,447,114,491,73,535,59,579,67,596,89,602,119,585,141,530,165,474,167" href="results?mylinks=Texas" <?php echo '<input type="text" name="Texas" value="Texas">' ?>  onclick="javascript:document.frmres.submit();return false;" />
</map>
</form>
```

I would like url to store: results.php?specialist_1=PILOT+mylink=Texas

Comment: So what is the expected user action?  He selects something in the dropdown and then click the image map?

Comment: Yes they select something in the drop box and also click a location on the map as part of the search.Drop down plus Map location on hotspot image.